# How to create node set from values

Tags: xslt, divide-and-conquer

How can we create a node set from values....

I have n numbers 1,2,3.......n.

I want to create a node set

```
<MYNMUMS>
<MYNUM>1</MYNUM>
<MYNUM>2</MYNUM>
<MYNUM>3</MYNUM>
<MYNUM>4</MYNUM>
....
<MYNUM>N</MYNUM>
</MYNMUMS>
```

Comment: Please give more clues what's a node set, what os, language etc.

Comment: A good question and the answer to it can be instructive to many people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*As easy as that*:

**XSLT 1.0 solution**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <MyNums>
       <xsl:call-template name="generateNumNodes">
         <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="1"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="10"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </MyNums>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="generateNumNodes">
      <xsl:param name="pStart"/>
      <xsl:param name="pEnd"/>

      <xsl:if test="$pEnd >= $pStart">
        <xsl:variable name="vNumNodes"
           select="$pStart -$pEnd+1"/>

        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$vNumNodes = 1">
            <MyNum><xsl:value-of select="$pStart"/></MyNum>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="vHalf" select=
              "floor(($pStart+$pEnd) div 2)"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="generateNumNodes">
              <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$pStart"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="$vHalf"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="generateNumNodes">
              <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$vHalf+1"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="$pEnd"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), produces the desired output**:

```
<MyNums>
   <MyNum>1</MyNum>
   <MyNum>2</MyNum>
   <MyNum>3</MyNum>
   <MyNum>4</MyNum>
   <MyNum>5</MyNum>
   <MyNum>6</MyNum>
   <MyNum>7</MyNum>
   <MyNum>8</MyNum>
   <MyNum>9</MyNum>
   <MyNum>10</MyNum>
</MyNums>
```

**Do note the following**:

1. **The template** `generateNumNodes` **calls itself recursively**.
2. **This recursion is both time `( O(N) )`,  and space `( O(log2(N)) )` efficient** and practically does overflow the stack -- no SO here!
3. The above feature is **achieved by implementing the recursion in a DVC** (`DiVide and Conquer`) **style**.
4. Unlike `tail-recursion` **it will be successfully executed on any compliant XSLT processor**.
5. **The maximum recursion depth needed to generate 1000000 (one million numbers) is just 19**.

**XSLT 2.0 solution**:

**Even more elementary, no recursion**, *just using the XPath 2.0 `to` operator*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <MyNums>
          <xsl:for-each select="1 to 10">
            <MyNums>
              <xsl:sequence select="."/>
            </MyNums>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </MyNums>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You cannot create an XSLT nodeset. Nodesets are obtained from source XML using selections or matching particular criteria, but cannot be created. This question is a bit misleading. The selected answer up the top is simply showing how to convert data in CSV format to XML.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is a transformation language. It is usually used when you already have some data in the form of an XML document, that you wish to transform into a different document (that may or may not be in XML format).

For the task of starting with "raw" data and generating an XML representation, XSLT is not well-suited.

I suggest you look into different langauges to solve this.

Comment: It is absolutely untrue that XSLT "is not well-suited" "for the task of starting with "raw" data and generating an XML representation".

Just two examples: 1. The f:json-document() function of FXSL, which uses a general LR-Parsing framework and a parser for JSON and produces an XML document from an instance of JSON. All written in pure XSLT. 

2. A parser for XPath 2.0, written in XSLt, which uses the same general LR-Parsing framework.

References:

[1] http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-json-document.xsl?revision=1.11&view=markup